# provision file error in iPhone OS 2.2

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I created an AppID "MyApp", DeviceID "MyDevice" in Program Portal and I downloaded the provision file and drag it to Organizer, downloaded the .cer file and install it on Mac.

All these works fine, but when I build my app, an error pops up saying "CodeSign error: a valid provisioning profile is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'Device-iPhone OS 2.2'".

I tried to find PROVISIONING_PROFILE in project.pbxproj in myApp.xcodeproj, but it returns "Not Found". What might be the problem? Do I need to modifiy the info.plist and what should I modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provisioning process for developing iPhone apps can be very confusing, and your error could be due to any of a number of issues. Here is a very thorough walkthrough:

http://www.24100.net/2009/02/iphone-sdk-mobile-provisioning-0xe800003a-0xe8000001/

I would suggest totally scrapping whatever provisioning profiles you have, erase them from XCode, and start over using this tutorial. That seems to work the best in most of my cases.

Comment: Thanks. The iPhone Untility Configuration is especially helpful for me(other ways of installing provisioning profile seems not work for iphone os 2.2).